# Jquery add and remove class on a menu

Tags: jquery

I'm newbie in jquery, I have this html code menu:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="navtab">
        <li class='home selected'><a href='index.php'>Home</a></li>
        <li class='about'><a href='company.php'>About</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

this is jquery code:

```
$(".navtab li.about").click(function(){
    $('.navtab li.home').removeClass('selected');
    $('.navtab li.about').addClass('selected');
});
```

and this my css:

```
nav ul.navtab li.selected a{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #575757;
}
```

When the page load tab home is selected. When I click on about tab I want to remove class selected on tab home and add class selected on tab about. Where is the problem??

Thanks in advance. Fabio

Comment: your code works fine what's your problem ?

Comment: Did you wrap your jQuery in `$(function(){ ... })`?

Comment: The click on about tab load page company.php, the home tab still has the class "selected" and the about tab hasn't the class "selected".

Answer (score 3):

use `removeClass('home.selected')` instead of `removeClass('selected');` also `$('.navtab li.home')` would be `$('.navtab li.home.selected')`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KuES6/3/)**

```
$("nav li.about").click(function(){  
     $('nav li.home.selected').removeClass('home selected');     
     $('nav li.about').addClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: I tuned my answer and also added a live demo link

Comment: The order in which the classes are applied makes a difference.. looks like there was no default class for home .. So when selected class was removed it still retained the selector color .. But if we have a default class for home  then  $('nav li.home').removeClass('selected') wii work !!

Comment: I updated my answer, fiddle is very slow and having difficulties working there.

Answer (score 1):

If you were loading pages on the client side do this instead:

```
$(function(){

    $(".navtab>li").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    });

});
```

This works when any list item is clicked.

If you are loading new pages on the server side then you need to set the selected class server side.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this solutions does not work or peraphs I didn't understand it!

Comment: +1 for enlightening me to .siblings(), useful.  PS fabio, yes it works, and is a better solution because you can use if for as many tabs as you have, and with one line.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to highlight selected section, you have to do it server side.

If you mess with classes client side **when you click a link**, page will be reloaded and jQuery callback will have no effect then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 'data-type=""' attribute or just use a name attribute to manage the on-states of this menu:

```
<nav>
<ul class="navtab">
<li class='home selected' id="homepage" name="nav_item"><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
<li class='about' id="company" name="nav_item"><a href='#'>About</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>​
```

And then here is the jQuery:

```
$("[name='nav_item']").click(function(){
$("[name='nav_item']").removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
});​
```

The jQuery removes all instances of the 'selected' class when a nav-item is clicked, then adds the 'selected' class to the link that was clicked. Let me know if this will work for you...I've made a jsFiddle of it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PLjc9/).

You can then use the ids for other things if you'd like. This just seems like a more efficient/cleaner way of doing it.

This will work as long as you're not refreshing the page...otherwise use your back-end code (PHP, JSP etc) to manage the on-states.

PHP example:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'homepage'){
    $selected_link = 'class="selected"'; //set the class if page is homepage
} else $selected_link = ''; //empty, will not throw and error
?>
```

Then your link:

```
<li class='home' id="homepage" <?php echo $selected_link;?>>
```

Comment: When I click on about tab there is a page refresh so I have resolve only with using php code that you suggest in the last message. I thought to solve with jquery.... thank you!!!

Comment: @Fabio - if this was your selcted answer please vote up or click the 'accepted answer'